# Get an instance of SoapContext

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How do I get an instance of the `SoapContext` class?

Something other than `RequestSoapContext.current`

Comment: Could you elaborate on your requirements?  What is it about  `RequestSoapContext.Current` that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Check out my answer then.  You access the SoapContext differently depending on whether you're a WebService Client, a Web Service, or within a custom filter.  You're probably running into something like that =)